# Coalesce in Hive returns null

Tags: sql, hive, coalesce

I want to take first non-missing value:

and it doesnt work properly

```
,coalesce(var1,var2,var3)
```

although

```
var1=null
var2=null
var3=variable
```

i got null as a result of coalesce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities.  The first is that all three are `null`.  You can test this by adding a fourth value that is a default to see if it is chosen.

My suspicion is the second possibility --  that `null` is really `'null'`.  If so, `coalesce()` will not work directly.

If this is the case, you can use `nullif()` or a `case` expression:

```
coalesce(case when var1 <> 'null' then var1 end), 
         case when var2 <> 'null' then var2),
         var3)
```

Comment: If null is really 'null', dont you think COALESCE will return 'null' rather than null.

Comment: I got error: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 9:18 Invalid function 'nullif':28:27, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Opera

Comment: @CharlottePanais, `nullif()` is short-hand in several SQL dialects for a `CASE` expression. In Hive, use `COALESCE(CASE WHEN var1 = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE var1 END,CASE WHEN var2 = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE var2...etc.` You see why the short-hand is nice, but the functionality is the same going the long way since Hive doesn't support the shortcut.

Comment: it seems that variable order in coalesce does matter. When i compile coalesce(var2,var3,var1) i got var3 (correct) and when i compile coalesce(var3,var1,var2) it also works correctly (givers var3). Why is it so?

Comment: what is more, function nvl also depends on order. i have another result when i compile nvl(nvl(var1,var2),var3) and another when i compile nvl((var3,var2),var1). WHY???